# Setting UID to User Other Than Root in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu-11.04, setuid

I am developing in C++ on NetBeans 6.9 on Ubuntu 11.04.  I am making a system() call which I would like to be called as user "peter" rather than as root.  I understand that

```
setuid(0);
```

sets the user to root but how does one set the user to peter?

Thanks,
Peter.

Comment: "peter" is not a user.  It is a string associated with a user.  Users are identified by number.  What you have to do is find out which user ID has a string "peter" associated with it.  `getpwnam` will help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perhaps want to search the password file for the correct user id via, e.g. [`getpwnam()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam).  Something like:

```
// look up peter's uid
uid_t peter_uid=getpwnam("peter")->pw_uid;

// Become peter
setuid(peter_uid);
seteuid(peter_uid);
```